# Initialization of an array of structs in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, initialization, c-strings

If I have a struct like below:

```
typedef struct MyStruct {
    char **str;
    int num;    
} MyStruct;
```

Is there a way for me to initialize an array of this structures. Perhaps like below:

```
const MyStruct MY_STRUCTS[] = {
    {
        {"Hello"}, 
        1
    },
    {
        {"my other string"}, 
        3
    },
};
```

Ultimately I would like to have a constantly declared array of structs inside a C++ class. How can this be done? Is it possible to have a privately declared member that is pre-initialized?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, you'd write it like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct MYStruct
{
     std::vector<std::string> str;
     int num;
};

MyStruct const data[] = { { { "Hello", "World" }, 1 }
                        , { { "my other string" }, 3 }
                        };
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding and you actually just want `num` to count the number of elements. Then you should just have:

```
std::vector<std::string> data[] = { { "Hello" }
                                  , { "my", "other", "string" }
                                  };
```

And you can recover the element sizes with `data[0].size()`, `data[1].size()`, etc.

---

If everything is determined statically and you just want a compact reference, you still need to provide storage, but everything is virtually the same as in C:

```
namespace    // internal linkage
{
    char const * a0[] = { "Hello" };
    char const * a1[] = { "my", "other", "string" };
    // ...
}

struct Foo
{
    char const ** data;
    std::size_t len;
};

Foo foo[] = { { a0, 1 }, { a1, 3 } };
```

Since the size is `std::distance(std::begin(a0), std::end(a0))`, you could simplify the last part with a macro that just takes `a0` as an argument. And instead of handwriting `Foo`, you might just use `std::pair<char const **, std::size_t>`.

Comment: Do I have to use a `vector` and a `string` to do this? Is there no way to do this with just `char**` and c arrays?

Comment: I really love your changes (`std::vector` instead of a pointer to an array, and `std::string` instead of a pointer to char), but I just noticed that the question specified c-style strings

Comment: @Akash: The short answer is "yes".

Comment: @Akash yes, its better: `std::vector`manages automagically its memory (That is, no manual-leak-prone-memory-management). The same for `std::string`. If you need the c-style string, you could use [`std::string::c_str()` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) (Long answer :) ).

Comment: @KerrekSB Is there a longer answer where you can use c strings and arrays; I would be interested in this answer because I might need it when working with embedded systems.

Comment: @Manu343726, in this case, does memory management matter since everything is a literal (I wanted to keep everything simple here because I will not use any functionality of an object here; the data is purely for ready-only reference)?

Comment: @Akash: Is everything determined statically?

Comment: @KerrekSB: yes, the data within array will be static and constant.

Comment: @Akash even if everything is not, as Kerrek is asking, determined statically, **pointers are not the solution here**. Note that the type of a string literal is an array of chars (`char[N]`, where N is the lengh of the string), and an array is an array, not a pointer

Comment: @Akash: Updated. Note that the actual storage for the elements needs to be named, but can have internal linkage. Same as in C, though there you'd use the `static` keyword instead of the unnamed namespace.

Comment: @Manu343726: I don't use that?!

Comment: Using c-strings and c-arrays did not work. I decided to just use vectors and strings instead.

Comment: can people PLEASE stop suggesting a vector? Vector is a heap allocated data structure!

Answer (score 6):

You mean something like this:

// In some headerfile:

```
class X
{
  private:
    static const MyStruct MY_STRUCTS[]; 
};
```

// in some .cpp file:

```
const X::MyStruct MY_STRUCTS[] = { { {"Hello"}, 1}, { "Other String"} , 3 } };
```

That assumes, however, that you have a `char *str;`, since `char **str;` requires a secondary variable to take the address off. Or, you could use `std::vector<string>`, and that would solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you can omit the array size in the class definition?

Comment: Yes, I would have thought so, for a `static` with only one dimension. But I'm not 100%.

Comment: This does not work when the first member of the struct is double pointer; you get an error along the lines of `Cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'const char **' with an lvalue of type 'const char [11]'`

Comment: Yes, that's what I said "This assumes ... " - use `vector<string>` or you'll have to declare a separate variable `const char *str1[] = { "x", "y" };`  and use `str1` as the input for `MY_STRUCTS`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
class foo {
    MyStruct array[2];
public:
    foo()
        : array{ { "a", 1 }, { "b", 2 }}
    {
    }
};
```

assuming you `struct`'s first member is actually `char const*` rather than `char**` as you initialization example suggests.

Comment: The first member of the struct is not just a char*, it will be an array of char*.

Comment: In this case you obviously can't initialize them with a string literal as in you example but you could provide the address of array of array of `char` instead: that's just the normal initialization rules.