# Initial Values of Elements of an Uninitialized Array of Structs in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, struct

If I have a struct that consists of two objects of a class, and I create an array of those structs **without initially setting the values of the objects to anything**, what will be contained in that array? Does it create structs using the default constructor for that struct?

My specific example requires me to use the last element of the array recursively to determine what the next element of the array is, and I need all the elements initially set to what the default constructor provides.

The array I am creating and the way I am declaring it is:

```
s arrayname [5];
```

My struct is essentially along the lines of:

```
struct s{
    Vectorh a, b;

    s();
}
```

where Vectorh is a class that contains four double values, plus a lot of functions. I also have a default constructor in this struct, which is defined as:

```
s(){
    a = Vectorh();             // Vectorh() creates a Vectorh with all components set
    b = Vectorh();             // to (double)0
}
```

Finally, Vectorh is defined as:

```
class Vectorh{
    double x, y, z, w;
}
```

with the constructors

```
Vectorh(double a, double b, double c){
    x = a;
    y = b;
    z = c;
    w = (double)0;
}
Vectorh(){
    x = (double)0;
    y = (double)0;
    z = (double)0;
    w = (double)0;
}
```

**Edit:** The linked question says nothing about empty initialization at all. It only talks about initialization with elements.

Comment: Yes, the default constructor will be used.

Comment: Use `... ={};` to value initialise the array.  Default is uninitialised.

Comment: It depends on the "struct". This can't be answered reasonably without more information.

Comment: @juanchopanza I added some information.

Comment: You need to include a **complete but minimal example** that readers can try as-is. For now voting to close as lacking such example.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Is there anything else that you need to answer this question?

Comment: No, the code you've given is sufficient. The default constructor is used, since you have defined one. However, please in future questions make sure that the code is technically valid, e.g. no lacking semicolons, and also that it's complete, e.g. no "essentially like". ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thank you. And when I said "essentially like," I just meant that I cut out everything that would not be relevant to the question like functions defined in Vectorh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialization of an array of structs in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938679/initialization-of-an-array-of-structs-in-c)